# Is it possible to ignore NA but not drop it in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe has 80 columns by 1 million rows.

There is a lot of NaN in the dataset, if I were to drop all NA values I would lose way too much data for it to be useful.

I was wondering if there was a way to go through the columns and when it would do any calculations later on, like mean, medium, mode, or more advanced calculations, it would just pretend the values aren't there.

It's not always as just NaN, it sometimes includes values like "Infinity" which should be ignored.

Is there something like:

```
Find NaN and Infinity in Dataframe, flag them and DO NOT CONSIDER them IN CALCULATIONS
```

I tried finding a command to do it but any information on it, maybe I'm just being silly.

Comment: You can fill NaN values by `df.fillna()` here `df` is your dataframe

Comment: @AnuragDabas, filling the `NaN` values will always influence the `mean` calculation, this is not desired.

Comment: then just use `numpy.nanmean()` It will not  influence the mean calculation and after that use `df.fillna()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `nanmean()` method in `numpy` for finding mean of particular column which has `NaN` values

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
series = pd.Series([np.nan, 1, np.nan, 3,np.nan,2])
mean=np.nanmean(series)
```

Now if you print this:-

```
 print(mean)
```

It gives `2.0` as output which means
It will not influence the mean calculation and after that use `df.fillna()`

```
series.fillna(mean,inplace=True)
```

Comment: Filling the `NaN` values can have unexpected consequences for the `median` and `mode`. Depending on the amount of `NaN` values, you could get both the `median` and the `mode` to equal the mean with which you just replaced all the `NaN` values. I would not go with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Some `pandas` functions automatically ignore `NaN` values. For example:

```py
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([np.nan, 1, 2, 3])
s.mean()
```

Gives the result `2.0`, so it ignores `NaN` values. Same goes for `median` and `mode`.

For the `inf` values, I would ask myself if they are actually meaningful. If they are not you can replace them with `NaN` for the `mean` calculation. The `median` and `mode` functions are already able to handle it.